# Android random - not quite random with 2 arrays

Tags: android, arrays, random

I want to pass my `Random`, depending on the users input, a variable amount of `Array`'s. Out of which the Randomizer should choose 1 line and a new one every time a button is pressed.

However, what I noticed is that the random first choose is between the given Arrays (which all contain different number of Lines), before picking a Line inside that Array. If one of the Arrays only contains a very small amount of Lines, it's likely that the Randomizer will return the same Line multiple times back-to-back. Instead of choosing between all lines in the given Arrays.

Is there a way to fix this issue so that every line has the same chance of getting picked?

```
int[] Options = {
      modeID, 
      sideID,
      //etc...
};

Random random = new Random();
int randomIndex = random.nextInt(Options.length);

String[] Output = getResources().getStringArray(Options[randomIndex]);
String randString = Output[random.nextInt(Output.length)];
random.setText(randString);
```

Comment: You could keep track of the previous chosen lines and rerun the nextInt function if it occurs to many times after each other

Comment: @RubenAalders I know that will eliminate the repeating, but given that 1 array contains more lines than an other (says 3 against 20), the chances of getting one of those 3 lines is way more likely than getting 1 of the 20 lines.

Comment: You could add a weight to each array on the size of the array. Say you will generate an int between 0 and 10. And your first array is a size of 10 and the second array a size of 30. You could pick a line of the first array when the number is below 3 and other wise pick a line from the other array. You could ofcourse also merge the Arrays.

Comment: Every random is not properly random , cause every algorithm is following a specific logic ! In the end you will not get never really random values.

Comment: @Frank I believe that is not the problem he is describing. I believe it is in: if you run it 100 times you should pick a line from each array 50 times. But the first array only has 3 items while the other has 20. So the same lines in the first array would occur more often

Comment: that's because random is not spreaded equally. So if you have 5 items, it won;t select all 5 just in random order.

Comment: @YankeeSierra Is there a reason why you cannot merge the arrays? It would be so much easier.

Comment: @RubenAalders It would. However, `modeID`, `sideID` etc. are already Integers (R.array.???), so it won't.

Comment: If the two arrays have 3 lines and 10 lines, then 3 + 10 = 13.  Pick a random number in 0..12.  Picking 0, 1, 2 means the appropriate line from the first array.  Picking 3..12 means the appropriate line from the larger array.  This gives all lines an equal chance of being picked, but more lines will come from the larger array, because there are more of them.